# Getting an error while viewing an activity. How to resolve it?

Tags: drupal, activities

***[image]***

> `

Blockquote

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
You are not authorized to access this page.
`

Answer (score 4):

The logged in user doen't have permission to view the activity. Does the activity type belong to Case? Or Non-Contact component? Do the user have edit all contact permission?